# multiple string [] to one gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, aspxgridview

I'm trying to display data from a web service each one returning string[] to one gridview.

the only that's seems to work for me is to call each string[] in a gridview , something like this :

```
string[] List1= client.GetProduitCarte(NumAbonne.Text, item).ToArray(); //* Web Service 1//
string[] Liste2 = client.GetServiceCarte(NumAbonne.Text, item).ToArray(); //* Web Service 2//
GridView1.DataSource = List1;
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView2.DataSource = List1;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

i want to display something like this is it's possible :

| List1 | List2 |
| --- | --- |
| data 1 of List1 | data 1 of List2 |
| data 2 of List1 | data 2 of List2 |

my front is :

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest shoving the two lists in to "one" data structure that THEN can be sent to the GV.

So, say this grid markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            CssClass="table table-hover"
            width="25%" >
        </asp:GridView>
```

Then in code we have 2 lists. But, one could be longer then the other.

We assume 2 lists of strings.

So, say this code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // make some fake data
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>(new string[] { "dog", "cat", "horse" });
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>(new string[] { "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4","L5","L6", "L7" });

        int MyRows = list1.Count >= list2.Count ? list1.Count : list2.Count;

        DataTable rData = new DataTable();
        rData.Columns.Add("List1");
        rData.Columns.Add("List2");

        for (int i = 0; i < MyRows; i++)
        {
            DataRow OneRow = rData.NewRow();

            if (i < list1.Count)
                OneRow["List1"] = list1[i];

            if (i < list2.Count)
                OneRow["List2"] = list2[i];

            rData.Rows.Add(OneRow);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = rData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And we get this:

[image]

## Edit: Asking if we can hide/not display empty rows

this idea will only work if the left side list is always longer.

The reason of course is if we "hide" the cell, then the columns will shuffer over by one.

So, we can add a row databound event.

Move the list1,2 to the page level class.
(since it will now be needed during row bind.

So, this code:

```
    List<string> list1 = new List<string>(new string[] { "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7" });
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>(new string[] { "dog", "cat", "horse" });

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // make some fake data
        int MyRows = list1.Count >= list2.Count ? list1.Count : list2.Count;

        DataTable rData = new DataTable();
        rData.Columns.Add("List1");
        rData.Columns.Add("List2");

        for (int i = 0; i < MyRows; i++)
        {
            DataRow OneRow = rData.NewRow();

            if (i < list1.Count)
                OneRow["List1"] = list1[i];

            if (i < list2.Count)
                OneRow["List2"] = list2[i];

            rData.Rows.Add(OneRow);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = rData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowIndex >= list1.Count)
                e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;

            if (e.Row.RowIndex >= list2.Count)
                e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;

        }
    }
```

So, it works ok, and gives this:

[image]

However, if I flip and have the left side list shorter, then the columns as noted will move over, and you get this effect:

[image]

Now, I suppose one might be able to hide the grid lines.

But, you can hide blank items.

Perhaps  better off to have two gv's side by side?

## Edit 3: We can hide the grid lines!!!

Try this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowIndex >= list1.Count)
                e.Row.Cells[0].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

            if (e.Row.RowIndex >= list2.Count)
                e.Row.Cells[1].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        }
    }
```

And we get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank for you help , it's makes a lot if sense for me now , my question is can we delete the empty rows in List1 for exampe ?

Comment: Well, this will only work if the left side list is LONGER then the right side. See my edit.

Comment: Actually, we can hide the grid lines - try my edit #3 -